# Tools for Second Order SQL Injection

Tags: sql-injection

Was doing a CTF where 2nd order SQL injection was needed. It's all been done manually but was interested whether there were tools that could have automated the process.

One page allowed you to add a query to a cell via a URL parameter and another page executed that query and put it in a nicely formatted table rather than just dumping the results of that query.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `sqlmap` has a second order parameter.

From the documentation :

`--second-order=S..  Resulting page URL searched for second-order response`.

See https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage for more informations.

Comment: Will it still work if the output of the executed query is specially formatted? into rows/columns?

Comment: I don't know. I guess yes, because of its powerful detection engine. The best way to know is probably to test on a vulnerable application made on purpose.

Comment: Done and done - worked nicely!